# All containers on a server fail to send SMTP requests, the rest works fine

Tags: debian, smtp

We have a VPS with several services in Docker containers, on top of which, another Docker container runs a Traefik reverse proxy.

Last Monday morning, all the services running on that server failed to send SMTP requests to our mail server hosted on another dedicated server.

That other server works fine, and we can send emails through it using Thunderbird, Mailspring, or the Modoboa web client running on the same dedicated server.

But the web client Roundcube (PHP based) hosted on the VPS fails to send emails. Another service failing to send emails is a Weblate (Django based) service showing this error message:

```
weblate.E003    Cannot send e-mail ([Errno 111] Connection refused), please check EMAIL_* settings.
```

I know the problem does not come from the configuration of those services, which ran uninterrupted since before the problem occurred. Nobody touched anything in the server when the issue appeared. The IP address is not blacklisted by the mail server. The rest of the services run normally, we receive emails on Roundcube, the other web apps are served properly.

I am open to any suggestion, and will keep editing the question based on your feedback. Thanks in advance.

### Added relevant details

- hostnamectl output:

```
   Static hostname: vps-ba3c567d
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: fa2a6b00e35e47d088520ae59c46e1ce
           Boot ID: dd72233a933f4fb88b108069c3f39943
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 5.10.0-26-cloud-amd64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

- the vps is hosted by OVH
- the cli history indicates nobody enter any command when the problem arose.

Comment: did you checked what the app is telling?, basically at the moment we do lack on information to reproduce. so I please you to read [ask] and update afterwards after reading it carefully

Comment: Thank you for commenting, @djdomi . I am not sure which app you are speaking about, there are several of them which all stopped to send SMTP request. I am mostly a web dev with little experience on server maintenance, I tried out using tools like telnet, openssl but I lack the general high level understanding on how those tools are supposed to behave in the first place and what they exactly do to figure out if I am on the good track when looking for the cause of the issue. I updated my question with informations on the server.

Comment: smpt is simple, its plain text - but you need to be an business administrator in a busniess envoirment to ask here, else you should move your question to superuser.com.
Just for first test, enter the Container or whatever, and try to telnet /nc the port of the smtp

Comment: "Someone discovered we are sending email and shut us down".